# How to pass basic authentication to API call in robotframework

Tags: python-3.x, rest, robotframework

I am trying to learn robot framework and I am trying to connect my https API using BASIC authentication. Can anyone help me to start with initial setup ?
Attached is the screenshot how Iam currently connecting the REST API.

An example I found on GITHUB looked promising but no idea how to use it in my case. https://github.com/jjwong/RESTinstance_starter_project/blob/master/tests/test_basic_authentication.robot  [image]

[image]

Comment: Please reduce the size of your images and only show the relevant part so that we do not need to click on it to actually see the details and we have no white blocks. Additionally can you share with us what you've already tried and what you observed.

Comment: In your case you want to make api call with auth token??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass credentials to RESTinstance POST Request in robot framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265635/how-to-pass-credentials-to-restinstance-post-request-in-robot-framework)

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add your username and password in headers of your request like

```
Authorization    Basic username:password
```

Note you need to encode it with base64.

**In case of Token based authentication**

```
Authorization    Bearer ${jwt_token}
```

Comment: The base64 encoding is not "might", it is required by the protocol. Note you're not answering the actual question "How to pass basic authentication to API call in robotframework".